# Ruby 2 Gem broken (can't 'list' or 'install')

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I just reinstalled ruby and now I'm facing some weird errors.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]

$ gem
      /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 3 column 29 (Psych::SyntaxError)
     from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
     from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
     from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
     from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:319:in `load_file'
     from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:192:in `initialize'
     from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `new'
     from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `do_configuration'
     from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:46:in `run'
     from /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure how to solve this. Does anyone know the issue?

Comment: The error message suggests that you have a broken YAML config file somewhere, a broken `~/.gemrc` perhaps?

Comment: Does error occur regardless of the current folder you're in?

Comment: @muistooshort What does the default ~/.gemrc file look like? I was seeing other signs pointing to a broken germrc too

Comment: Probably depends on the version of `gem`, move it out of the way and see what happens.